# How do I check I am safe to run rendom /clean

Tags: active-directory

I am running an AD that has been renamed at some point in the past. I don't know when (one of my predecessors did it). I don't know for certain if it has been completed successfully. The only remaining evidence I can find is the msDS-DnsRootAlias attribute still exists causing DNS some issues when trying to update root servers outside of the domain.

I have read the technet article on renaming a domain
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208(v=ws.10).aspx
and I get the impression that the AD would not be in a working state if the rename had not finished.

Does this mean I am safe to run rendom /clean ?

Is there anything I can check other than looking for the log files (Looked I can't find it in old sysadmin user folders or on c:)

Comment: Have all domain member computers been restarted twice ?

Comment: here's the step-by-step domain rename procedure i've used in the past, it may help:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/c/cfcbff04-97ca-4fca-9e8c-3a9c90a2a2e2/Domain-Rename-Procedure.doc

Comment: I am certain they have all been restarted at least twice.